# About convergence in distribution and characteristic functions

Tags: probability

I've been recently studying some probability theory and came across this problem in the lecture note, which states:

if $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in distribution, $Y_{n}$ converges to $Y$ in distribution, for all n, $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are independent, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then does $X_{n}+Y_{n}$ converge to $X+Y$ in distribution?

I was asked to prove this using characteristic functions. So I tried to use exponential distribution to show that when $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ follow Exp(n), $\phi_{X_{n}}\phi_{Y_{n}}$
would converge to 1 but $\phi_{X}\phi_{Y}$ would be 0 since $d\mu_{X_{n}}$ would converge to 0 a.e. But I'm not sure if this proof itself is correct. I'd appreciate any sort of help about this problem. Much thanks.

Comment: In this case $X$ and $Y$ would both be zero so $\phi_X(t)=\phi_Y(t)=1$ for all $t$. So there is no issue here.

Comment: Showing this only for the exponential distribution is not a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, as shown in the following computation.
For each $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have, by using independence twice:
$$\phi_{X_n + Y_n}(t) = \phi_{X_n}(t) \phi_{Y_n}(t) \to \phi_X (t) \phi_Y(t) = \phi_{X+Y}(t)$$
showing that the characteristic function of $X_n + Y_n$ converges pointwise to the characteristic function of $X+Y$. By Lévy's continuity theorem, this implies that $X_n + Y_n$ converges in distribution to $X+Y$.